# Celery - a task runs N tasks, waits for them and processes the results

Tags: python, celery

I need the following workflow:

- `ParentTask` is run first
- At some point, it spawns N instances of `ChildTask`, which run in parallel
- `ParentTask` waits for those to finish, collects the results, processes them somehow and finishes

This seems to be very easy. Unfortunately, calling `Task().delay()` (which I use to invoke tasks) from within a task seems to get completely ignored. I am completely lost here.

If you like code approach more, I include it as well.

```
from celery.task import Task
from celery.result import AsyncResult

class ParentTask(Task):
    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # do some stuff
        ids = [ChildTask().delay().id for _ in range(N)] # this seems to do nothing here
        results = [AsyncResult(t) for t in ids]
        while not all([r.ready() for r in results]): # wait for child tasks to finish
            sleep(.100)
        # do some stuff again
        # return results

class ChildTask(Task):
    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # do some child stuff
        # return child results

ParentTask().delay() # this delay works fine
```

Thanks for any clues!

Comment: You need [Canvas](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#groups)

Comment: Can I combine those groups, chains, chords etc. together? If so, could you please write a code snippet for me which shows the usage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it. A working approach can look like this (of course, the tasks can do whatever stuff is needed):

```
from time import sleep
from celery.task import Task
from celery import chain, group

class PreTask(Task):
    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        x = 0
        for i in range(100000):
            x += 1
        return x


class MidTask(Task):
    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        sleep(5)
        return 42


class PostTask(Task):
    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return args


# call it like this
res = chain(PreTask().s() | group(MidTask().s() for _ in range(5)) | PostTask().s()).apply_async()

# and get the result for example like this
while(True):
    if res.ready():
        print(res.get())
    sleep(1)
```

Hope it helps someone.